# Using Meta Description for Tag Pages

Tags: seo, meta-tags, tags

Lot of my tagged pages in magento have good search engine rankings, but I am getting a low click-through rate for them. Is it possible through any extension or code snippet that few of my tagged pages has meta-description in them that shows in search engines.

Comment: You want a mete description in cms page or product page\

Comment: @LearningMagento in tagged pages e.g. mysite.com/tag/product/list/tagId/220/